# Flutter. add Text below Container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

This is a simple URL Browser launcher.
I want to add text below the container.

Do I use a Stack or Children?

Any solutions will be grateful.

Thank you

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( 
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Welcome"),
         centerTitle: true,
         backgroundColor: Colors.black,
         ),      
      body: Container(      
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Container( 
            height:200, 
            width:double.infinity,
            color: Colors.black,
               child: Center( 
               child: ElevatedButton( 
                  child: Text("Click Here"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    String url = "https://www.google.com/";
                    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                    var urllaunchable = await canLaunch(url); //canLaunch is from url_launcher package
                    if(urllaunchable){
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        await launch(url); //launch is from url_launcher package to launch URL
                    }else{
                       print("URL can't be launched.");
                     }
                  },
               )
            ),
         )
      ) 
    );
  }
}
```

[ImageScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai1T5.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it inside `Column`, like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Welcome"),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Container(
                  height:200,
                  width:double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Center(
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        child: Text("Click Here"),
                        onPressed: () async {
                        },
                      )
                  ),
                )
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50,),
            Text("Your Text")
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```